# SQL Server Profiler : capture calls to your database's stored procs during SSRS report generation

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-profiler

Using SQL Server/SSRS 2008.

With SQL Server Profiler, I've been unsuccessfully trying to trace SSRS (rdl) report generation calls to my database's stored procs i.e. so I can see what parameter values are being passed etc.

What events should I be looking for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Events:

**In Stored Procedures** group

- RPC:Completed
- RPC:Starting (if completed is not called because of error in proc)

If your proc is called as usual Sql Query, then:

In **TSQL** group

- SQL: Batch Starting
- SQL: Batch Completed

Comment: thanks, that did it. (LOL, I was capturing RPC completed, but the "TextData" column had not been ticked).

Comment: You could get the parameters passed to the report without having to run a trace by looking at the Parameters column of the executionlog view in the SSRS catalog database.

Comment: These same options are also specified in this article ([RedGate: How to Identify Slow Running Queries with SQL Profiler](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/how-to-identify-slow-running-queries-with-sql-profiler/)), with only slight variation-- **Excluded**: `[RPC:Starting]`, **Included**: `[SP:StmtCompleted], [Showplan XML]`.